# Log all exceptions in service fabric application

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a bunch of backend service in Azure Service Fabric, I want to log any uncaught exceptions to App Insights, along with all my other logs. Is there any way in an Azure Service Farbic app to catch all uncaught exceptions and log them before re-throwing them?

Answer (score 0):

You're using .net so you have access to the standard AppDomain way of handling all uncaught exceptions. Use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Add the following lines into your Program.cs with logging code in there

```
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender,e)
      => {
//log exception

};
```

Comment: This never catches any exception, possibly because this is a service fabric app. If I do a thow new Exception() in any of the public methods of the app, then call the method, then the error is not caught in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

For sending application/service telemetry to Application Insights, I strongly recommend you have a look at [App Insights Service Fabric](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-ServiceFabric). It works great for:

- Sending error and exception info
- Populating the application map with all your services and their dependencies (including database)
- Reporting on app performance metrics, as well as,
- Tracing service call dependencies end-to-end,
- Integrating with native as well as non-native SF applications

If you're also interesting in monitoring the overall health of your cluster (e.g. CPU/Memory and when nodes go up/down), have a look at [EventFlow](https://github.com/Azure/diagnostics-eventflow) or this [github](https://github.com/Adebeer/Service-Fabric-AppInsights-Health-Monitor) project